Can't use multiprocessing inside exec function in python
I need to use multiprocessing inside an exec function, but I'm getting an error.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    exec('''from multiprocessing import Pool
def func():
    print(1)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool(4) as pool:
        pool.apply_async(func)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()''')

When executed, the following error occurs.
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'func' on <module '__mp_main__' from 'filename'>
The above is the code in question, and if I remove the if __name__ == "__main__" the top, it works fine.
But that if __name__ == "__main__" is absolutely necessary.

By defining the function func within the name guard if __name__ == "__main__":, the spawned child processes, whose __name__ is '__mp_main__', don't get to execute the def func() statement to have the function defined in their namespace, hence the AttributeError.
You should define objects that child processes need outside the name guard instead:
def func():
    print(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    exec('''from multiprocessing import Pool
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        with Pool(4) as pool:
            pool.apply_async(func)
            pool.close()
            pool.join()''')


thank you.
However, the first if __name__ == "__main__" is absolutely necessary.

I omitted it because you already have a redundant name guard in the code passed to exec. But it's OK if you retain both name guards because one of them is redundant anyway. I've updated my answer with both name guards retained.

I'm sorry.
There must be func() inside if __name__ == "__main__".

But why? As I explained, placing def func() inside if __name__ == "__main__" will prevent child processes from having the function defined. What exactly is forcing you to do so?

This is because multiple functions are used in multiprocessing, and the function (string) created with that function needs to be executed with the exec function.
Because you need to if __name__ == "__main__" until all processes are terminated.
